# ActiveMQ producer generating heapdump

Tags: java, activemq-classic, fuseesb, heap-dump, jbossfuse

We are using Jboss FuseESB Active MQ on IBM AIX machine. We are sending upto 10000 requests per day to consumer. Each request has about 10Kb size. We are getting heap dump in every 3 days. Here is image of IBM Heap Analyzer.

Right before  heap is generated, there are upto I think JMS messages are getting processed slowly by consumer. What are strategies to increase the processing speed of JMS consumer.

**Edit:**

Here is image of Heap Analyzer:

[image]

**Edit:**

We are using embedded broker. Here is activemq.xml that we are using:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org /schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties and fabric as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <bean class="org.fusesource.mq.fabric.ConfigurationProperties"/>
    </property>      
</bean>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        brokerName="${broker-name}"
        dataDirectory="${data}"
        start="false">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" queuePrefetch="1">
                  <deadLetterStrategy>
                       <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ."/>
                  </deadLetterStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter> 


<!--

<plugins>
        <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="karaf" />
    </plugins>
-->
    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="128 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>


    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:0?maximumConnections=1000"/>
    </transportConnectors>
</broker>
</beans>
```

Comment: very little detail here.  Am I right in assuming that you in fact use an embedded broker?  Also, What's your persistence configuration, if any?  Because with persistence disabled you force the broker to keep all intransit messages in memory, which could explain the OOM issue.  Nevertheless, even with bigger intermediate storage you are obviously in trouble if you're consuming slower than you produce, and you should consider either speeding up the consumer, giving it a faster machine to run on, or have several processes attached as consumers to the queue, if your architecture allows that.

Comment: I added activemq.xml to edit. Also we are using in kahadb for persistence.

Comment: it is not clear from your heapdump image who owns the objects taking up the memory.  can you do more analysis there and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are any Queue and/or durable topic subscribers that are not started and that their messages are persisted in the JMS broker?

You should browse the JMS destinations, for example using JMX, and identify the messages and their consumers. If you checked that every consumer is correctly configured and running, debug why the messages are consumed that slowly.